# Sort Customer and Product details in magento SOAP API

Tags: php, api, magento, sorting, soap

Is there  any predefined function/method using magento SOAP API  to getting customer,product other details in sorted List/data. 
I want to sort customer details by email, last name ,first name or by other detail Using  Magento SOAP API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if(isset($_REQUEST['field_name']))
    {
       $collection = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->getCollection()->addAttributeToSelect('*');
       $collection->setOrder($_REQUEST['field_name'],'ASC');
       $collection->load();
       $data=$collection->toArray();
}
```

I used above code and it work. We can put any thing like first name ,last name,email etc in place of field_name and it will short according to it.

Answer (score 1):

You should check in

```
app/code/core/Mage/Customer/Model/Customer/Api.php
```

There is a function called `items()` that will help you retrieve a table containing customer info.

You can use it by calling: `'customer.list'` and passing the wanted filters as and array of arguments.

Answer (score 0):

This can help you..

```
$collection = Mage::getModel("xxx")->getCollection()
            ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
             ->addAttributeToSort('last_name', 'ASC');
```

Comment: I am using the following code but it does not work.
                                                                     $collection = Mage::getModel("customer/customer")-           >getCollection()
     ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
     ->addAttributeToSort('lastname', 'ASC');

Comment: addAttributeToSort('last_name', 'ASC') It should be last_name not lastname